# checkbox not checked but the row of grid selected dojo

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I have Data Grid with selector type `checkbox`.

I observed on debugging that the checkbox is ticked initially but checkbox gets not checked when the code moves to `dojo.js`
 ` var tab=declare([Grid,Pagination,Keyboard,ColumnResizer, ColumnReorder,        Selection, selector, DijitRegistry]); grid = new tab({ store: myStore, id: "addInfoGrid", minRowsPerPage: 25, maxRowsPerPage: 6000, bufferRows: 15000, getBeforePut: false, deselectOnRefresh: false, selectorType: "checkbox", allowSelectAll: true, selectionMode: "none", cellNavigation: true,

columns: {
            rowSel: selector({
                label: "Select",
                selectorType: "checkbox",
                width: 20
            }),
            step: {
                label: i18n.step,
                width: "autowidth"}});`

Comment: please share the code snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chekbox not ticked even after clicking it in dojo grid but the row is selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784280/chekbox-not-ticked-even-after-clicking-it-in-dojo-grid-but-the-row-is-selected)